# Label caption is not set in label background center

Tags: blackberry

I am working on a logic where I have to align the label caption in vertically center but it's not working.

I have tried to set text padding but the whole label with background is shifting.Is there any way to solve this.

Here is my code:

```java
final Bitmap tabBackGroundImage1 = Bitmap.getBitmapResource("box_img.png");
homeContentManager.setBorder( BorderFactory.createBitmapBorder(
    new XYEdges(16,16,16,16), tabBackGroundImage));
//homeContentManager.setBorder(roundedBourder);

//HOME SCREEN HORIZONTAL MANAGER
buddiesLabel=new LabelField("Buddies");

_bitmap = EncodedImage.getEncodedImageResource("buddies.png");
final BitmapField buddiesBmp = new BitmapField(Constant.sizePic(_bitmap, 
                                      _bitmap.getHeight(), _bitmap.getWidth()));
buddiesBmp.setMargin(3,5,0,5);

if(BuddyListField.onlineBuddyCount < 1000) {
    buddyCount=new LabelField(" "+BuddyListField.onlineBuddyCount+" "){
        /*public void setText(String text,int offset,int length){
            text = String.valueOf(BuddyListField.onlineBuddyCount);
            offset = 200;
            length = 5;
            super.setText(text, offset, length);
        }*/
        public int getPreferredHeight() {
            return tabBackGroundImage1.getHeight();
        }
        public int getPreferredWidth() {
            return  tabBackGroundImage1.getWidth();
        }

        protected void layout(int width, int height) {
            super.layout(width, height);
            setExtent(Math.min(width, tabBackGroundImage1.getWidth()), Math.min(height, tabBackGroundImage1.getHeight()));
        }
        protected void paint(Graphics graphics) {
            int deviceWidth=net.rim.device.api.system.Display.getWidth();
            int deviceHeight=net.rim.device.api.system.Display.getHeight();

            graphics.clear();
            graphics.drawBitmap(0, 0, deviceWidth,
            deviceHeight, tabBackGroundImage1, 0, 0);
            super.paint(graphics);
        }
    };
```

This is the output:

[image]

But I need to set zero to vertically center in background.

Comment: It's hard to debug your code, because we don't know which bitmap is which here.  Which is buddies.png and which is box_img.png?  It looks like you probably are showing us code for one label, and one image that has nothing to do with your problem.  Please don't do that.  Cut out the code that doesn't apply to this, and just show us the code for this one label/image combination.  Thanks.  It would also help if you actually uploaded the background (yellow bubble) image, and pasted it in your question.  Not a screenshot of it.  The **exact** image.  That way, we can tell what its size is, too.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

```
protected void paint(Graphics graphics) {
            int deviceWidth=net.rim.device.api.system.Display.getWidth();
            int deviceHeight=net.rim.device.api.system.Display.getHeight();

            graphics.clear();
            graphics.drawBitmap(0, 0, deviceWidth,
            deviceHeight, tabBackGroundImage1, 0, 0);

            graphics.drawText((getPreferredWidth()-getText())/2,(getPreferredHeight()-graphics.getFont().getHeight())/2,getText);

//            super.paint(graphics);
        }
```